# How to set the Content-Type response header in Vapor 4?

Tags: swift, httpresponse, content-type, vapor

My application uses Vapor 4.3 and has a simple route that sends an HTML snippet as a response:

```swift
import Vapor

func routes(_ app: Application) throws {
  app.get("hello") { _ -> String in
    "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>"
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this response doesn't have a correct `Content-Type` HTTP header set on it, so it doesn't render as proper HTML when this route is opened in a browser. What's the best way to set the `Content-Type` header on this response?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to return `Response` like this

```swift
app.get("hello") { _ -> Response in
    var headers = HTTPHeaders()
    headers.add(name: .contentType, value: "text/html")
    let html = "<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>"
    return Response(status: .ok, headers: headers, body: .init(string: html))
}
```

Comment: returning just `req.headers` is a bad practise